# Strong params on a hash or array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In rails I did this in **a model**:

```
  def update_user_ex(*attrs)
    user.assign_attributes(*attrs) 
    # .............
```

where `attrs` is an  **array** with of a hash(es), for simplicity let's say it's a single hash.

How can I do this in Rails 4? "permit" doesn't work on a hash or array.

Comment: @mudasobwa, update a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use strong parameters outside of controllers per the documentation at https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Example:

```
def update_user_ex(*attrs)
  params = ActionController::Parameters.new(attrs)
  user.assign_attributes(params.permit(:name, :email, :something_else))
```

Comment: You said single hash for simplicity's sake. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you could merge your array of hashes into a single hash with the following:  `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(attrs.reduce({}, :merge))`

Comment: how can I chain parameters? `params.permit(:aaa).permit(:bbb)` doesn't work because it returns an empty hash

Answer (score 0):

Permit do work on arrays in rails 4. But array need to be last parameter.

```
params.require(:test).permit(:name,:rollno, question_ids:[])
```

The below example give error as array is not last parameter.

```
params.require(:test).permit(question_ids:[], :rollno)
```

Comment: how can I chain parameters? params.permit(:aaa).permit(:bbb) doesn't work because it returns an empty hash

Comment: @Johshi: why would you want to chain permits like that?